# Stencil.js link and require or import multiple Stencil projects in one Vue.js Project?

Tags: git, vue.js, import, module, stenciljs

I was trying to import multiple Stencil.js projects in my vue project... 
I did as described here for one stencil project:
https://stenciljs.com/docs/vue

however, for multiple stencil projects, I would have to import applyPolyFills and defineCustomElements  multiple times from different stencil packages and this does not work... how would I do that? Or do I need to import it only once?

Furthermore, my stencil projects are not publicly published in the npm registry.. I use my local repo from git and do a npm link.. therefore I can't do npm install  and it also won't install directly from the git repo as I don't have ssh permissions somehow... (altough I have full access rights to the repo)... So I don't know how to do it for multiple stencil imports ....

Comment: You probably need to do the `applyPolyFills` only once (doesn't matter which lib it's imported from) and then import `defineCustomElements` from each package and run them one after another.

Comment: ok and how do I use defineCustomElements(...) to register my stencil files or folders (or what do I register anyway) ?

Comment: https://stenciljs.com/docs/vue or https://stenciljs.com/docs/javascript

Comment: its only the example for one stencil component...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way how to import several stencil projects, you have to call `defineCustomElements` one by one from each project.

```
import { defineCustomElements as firstProjLoader } from “stencil-project-1/loader”

import { defineCustomElements as secondProjLoader } from “stencil-project-2/loader”

firstProjLoader();
secondProjLoader();
```